# How to give nodes a specific placement order in a Drupal View using a flag

Tags: php, drupal, view

Say I have a View with 20 nodes.  I want to display all 20 nodes in order by date, except say 6 nodes I want to give specific placement by setting a flag on the content type.  The first 12 spots in the view would display nodes with my special flag in the odd numbered spots 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 and 11.  The even numbered spots would be filled with unflagged nodes in the order they would normally appear by date.

How can I achieve this?  Would I use a group? A relationship?  Please point me in the right direction if you can.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can order results by more then one criteria. Order them first by your flag field and then by date.